# the glossaryentries aren't reflected when using loadglsentries

Tags: glossaries

When I try to `\loadglsentries` from a separate glossary file which I created, they aren't reflected in the document. On the other hand when I include the `\newglossaryentry` in the `main.tex`, they are reflected. I checked the `.glo` file too, it gets modified on every build but it only shows the old entries which were added when I included the `\newglossaryentry` in my `main.tex` file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}%to make itemize bold
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}% to make image caption bold
\usepackage{color,soul}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\nocite{*}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue
}

\newlist{arrowlist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[arrowlist]{label=$\Rightarrow$}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

% to setup the chapter formatting
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{8pt}{\LARGE }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{8pt}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newenvironment{dedication}
\loadglsentries{abbreviations.tex}
\makeglossaries


    \begin{document}    
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    \input{Abstract}

    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures

    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \listoftables
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
    \input{Chapter1}

    \chapter{Literature Review and Background into EDDL}\label{ch:chapter 2}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
    \input{Chapter2}


    \chapter{Methodology}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
    \input{Chapter4}

    \chapter{Observations}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
    \input{Chapter5}

    \chapter{Conclusion}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
    \input{Chapter6}

    \chapter{Future Scope}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
    \input{Chapter7}

\printbibliography[title=References]
\glsaddall
\printglossary[title=Abbreviations]
\end{document}
```

my `abbreviations.tex` file looks like this

```
\newglossaryentry{opcua}{name={OPC UA},description={Open Platform Communications Unified Architecture}}

\newglossaryentry{eddl}{name={EDDL},description={Electronic Device Description Language}}

\newglossaryentry{fdt}{name={FDT},description={Field Device Tool (frame application)}}

\newglossaryentry{dtm}{name={DTM},description={Device Type Manager (device driver)}}

\newglossaryentry{fdi}{name={FDI},description={Field Device Integration}}

\newglossaryentry{gui}{name={GUI},description={Graphical User Interface}}

\newglossaryentry{iec}{name={IEC},description={International Electrotechnical Commission}}

\newglossaryentry{ne}{name={NE},description={NAMUR Empfehlungen}}
```

Updated the code. I have now posted almost the entire code from main.tex file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This works for me. Did you run the `makeglossaries` perl script after `pdflatex`?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm using TexStudio. So after building which effectively runs pdflatex I ran tools -> Glossary, which I think runs makeglossaries.

Comment: Try to use `\loadglsentries` after `\makeglossaries`. Off-topic: `acronym` and `glossaries` is a little too much. The `glossaries` package provides `acronym` support too

Comment: Gives me an error, asking me to include in `\begin{document}`

Comment: I meant `\loadglsentries` after `\makeglossaries`, but before `\begin{document}` of course

Comment: Does it work when you use the above code? I actually have a whole lot of code in addition to what is mentioned above, but I posted only the relevant code

Comment: Yes, it works out of the box as you posted above (I compile on TeXLive 2015, daily updated, on Linux, without special editor -- console compilation)

Comment: yes I put it before `\begin{document}`, however its prompting such an error. I think its simply a side effect.

Comment: I tried creating a test project and yes, it works in that. Now I'm really confused as to what is causing the above mentioned problem.

Comment: \glsaddall 
\printglossary[title=Abbreviations]
\end{document} . This is almost my entire code. Could you try this on your system?

Comment: my bad..will do it

Comment: I'll take a look, but `\input{abstract}` isn't really helpful. We haven't those files. I'll try to comment them out in my local copy here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it works now, I tried commenting out the line \newenvironment{dedication} and now it seems to work. I'm not sure of the reason though.

Comment: Yes, I just found it -- the `\newenvironment` is wrongly used there!

Answer (score 2):

The reason was `\newenvironment}{dedication}` which is wrong in the sense that `\newenvironment` needs two other arguments. Those were grabbed in using `\loadglsentries{...}` and `\makeglossaries` with the effect that those commands weren't called, since `dedication` is not used at all so far in this code.

I've replaced it with

```
 \newenvironment{dedication}{}{}
```

which is useless at the moment (since it doesn't do anything)

Some notes on the code:

- `fixltx2e` isn't needed any longer since 2015 LaTeX core update
- `hyperref` should be one of the last packages
- `glossaries` should come after `hyperref`

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\usepackage{enumitem}%to make itemize bold
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % Not really needed any longer since 2015 format 
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}% to make image caption bold
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\nocite{*}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue
}

\newlist{arrowlist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[arrowlist]{label=$\Rightarrow$}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}


\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

% to setup the chapter formatting
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{8pt}{\LARGE }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{8pt}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newenvironment{dedication}{}{}

\loadglsentries{abbreviations}
\makeglossaries


    \begin{document}    
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \chapter*{Abstract}
%    \input{Abstract}

    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures

    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \listoftables
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
%    \input{Chapter1}

    \chapter{Literature Review and Background into EDDL}\label{ch:chapter 2}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
%    \input{Chapter2}


    \chapter{Methodology}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
%    \input{Chapter4}

    \chapter{Observations}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
%    \input{Chapter5}

    \chapter{Conclusion}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
%    \input{Chapter6}

    \chapter{Future Scope}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
%    \input{Chapter7}

\printbibliography[title=References]
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=main,title=Abbreviations]
\end{document}
```